# On the Cramér-Granville Conjecture and finding prime pairs whose difference is 666

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, mathematical-modeling, sieve-theory

**Questions**

If $p= \text{NextPrime}[q]$ (the smallest prime greater than $p$), and $p-q = 666,$ what are $p$ and $q$?

(There may be multiple choices. I am interested in finding one.)

> Cramér-Granville Conjecture:
>   Defining $p_0=2$, and $p_n$ as the nth odd prime, and the nth prime gap as
>   $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$, then  $g_n< M \log(p_n)^2$ for some $M>1$.

Reference link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cramer-GranvilleConjecture.html

If $g_n =666$,  what are generally good estimates for $M$ and $p_n$ according to the
Cramér-Granville Conjecture? Can we make use of current sieve technology and probabilistic modeling to solve our problem efficiently?

---

**Commentary & Previous Work**

If $g_n = 666$ and $p_n = 18691113008663$, then the conjecture is satisfied for any $M>1$.

We let  $\text{primegap}_{avg} = x/\pi(x) = g_n = 666$. 
If $\pi(x) = x/(li(x) + sqrt(x) * log(x)/(8\pi))$, then we have  $x/\pi(x) = 666$ which implies $x = 4.73231\times10^{289}$ and $\pi(x) =7.10558\times10^{286}$.  So our upper bound estimate of $p_n$ will be less than $4.73231\times10^{289}$.

Therefore, we shall focus our attention on finding consecutive prime pairs whose difference is $666$ in the open interval, $(18691113009329, 4.73231*10^{289})$. And we should expect to find approximately $(c/333)(\pi(4.73231×10^{289})-\pi(18691113009329)) = c *7.10558×10^{286}/333$, or $c * 2.133808*10^{284}$ consecutive prime pairs whose difference is $666$ where 
$0.5 < c < 1$.

Note:  $c \to 1$ as $x\to\infty$ according to the Polignac Conjecture.

Furthermore, we also expect to discover sufficiently many prime gaps greater than $666$ in the open interval, $(18691113009329, 4.73231×10^{289})$, so that the prime gap density or average of $666$ is maintained.  And according to the Cramér-Granville Conjecture, the maximum prime gap of $\log(4.73231\times10^{289})^2 = 444892$, more or less, exists in the open interval.

---

**Reference links**

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/#comment-472548;

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1989-52-185/S0025-5718-1989-0947470-1/S0025-5718-1989-0947470-1.pdf/;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture;

https://www.quora.com/What-great-conjectures-in-mathematics-combine-additive-theory-of-numbers-with-the-multiplicative-theory-of-numbers/answer/David-Cole-146;

https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/prime-number-theory1.pdf;

Boeyens, Jan C. A.; Levendis, Demetrius C. (2008), Number Theory and the Periodicity of Matter, Berlin: Springer-Verlag, ISBN 978-1-4020-6659-7;

'A Primer in Density Functional Theory', http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-37072-2;

https://www.wired.com/2016/11/physicists-uncover-strange-numbers-particle-collisions/.

***“Repetition and growth of prime gaps are essential for the efficient generation of the integers.”***

Comment: What a strange choice of number...

Comment: No Idea. However, $q >   7,177,162,611,713$

Comment: @Simple Art Halloween is near!  Watch out for those skeletons... :-)

Comment: According to the "prime gap" wikipedia page, it is more than $7,177,162,611,713.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: @Will  Did you apply Cramer-Granville conjecture to get your result?

Comment: He got the same answer exactly as me, so I'm guessing he visited a similar list of "maximal prime gaps." @Dave

Comment: Is this question of any use?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci  I hope so.  I have been trying to find a counterexample to the Polignac Conjecture.

Comment: @Barry Cipra  Thanks!! :-)

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  I will not bet against it ... :-)

Comment: So why were you trying to find a counterexample then? There is none.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  Do you know a formal proof of Polignac Conjecture?

Comment: No, but I also don't have a formal proof of RH. But  it is true anyway:)

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  Hmm.  Proof is true confidence!   Without proof, counterexamples are possible.  :-)

Comment: The question is put on hold, meaning that it is not possible to submit another answer. Since you asked the question some days ago, it has been changed considerably but it's still closed. If I were you, I would have asked another question instead because now it looks more interesting than the original one.

Comment: @polfosol Thanks!  Can you ask such a question?  Please keep the ball rolling...

Comment: @polfosol Please keep me in the loop on this stuff.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can also use prime number theorem to get an *estimation*. Something like:
$$\text{Find }x\text{ such that}\\\;\\ \frac{x+666}{\ln(x+666)}=\frac{x}{\ln x}+1$$
**Edit:**

Thanks to the online Wolfram Cloud, I came up with something like this:

```
gap[x_,d_]:=(x+d)/Log[x+d]-x/Log[x]-1;
FindRoot[gap[x,666],{x,1000}]
```

which resulted in $x=3.8013\times 10^{17}$

Comment: This answer calculate when the *average* gap reaches 666.  The question was only for a a single example, which is found far earlier.

Comment: @StigHemmer And I used the word _estimation_ for a purpose. If you know the order of magnitude, the search would be easier

Comment: @polfosol Your estimate is off by 4 orders of magnitude.  Because it's estimating the wrong thing.

Comment: @innisfree OK, I give up. Maybe we have the wrong idea about the order of magnitude. I mean, if I wanted to do a brute-force search for such number, I would have first evaluated to see what I am dealing with. Of course this estimate is too far, but at least I know that I shouln't start with numbers less than say, 100 million...

Comment: And by the way, the value that WolframCloud gave me is the result of an overflow! The actual value for which `gap[x,666]=0` is much much larger

Comment: @polfosol  Is there a way to combine your formula with current state of art of sieve algorithms to quickly generate primes, p_n and p_n+1, whose difference is 666?  I think the Cramer-Andrew conjecture is helpful too.

Comment: @Dave I am working on it. It seems to be an interesting topic. I'll keep you posted if anything new comes up

Comment: @polfosol Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 36):

According to the [table](https://faculty.lynchburg.edu/%7Enicely/gaps/gaplist.html#MainTable) compiled by Thomas Nicely, $q=18{,}691{,}113{,}008{,}663$ is the first occurrence of $666$ as a prime gap.  Nicely attributes the value to a [1989 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1989-52-185/S0025-5718-1989-0947470-1/S0025-5718-1989-0947470-1.pdf) by Jeff Young and Aaron Potler.

Comment: +1 I was about to give $2222222222222240257$ (found by trial an error, not very satisfying!), but your answer is more useful I think :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I'd be curious to hear how trial and error led you to that number.

Comment: @Barry Cipra and Jean-Claude Arbaut  Thanks!! :-)

Comment: @BarryCipra Dirty approach: start with some more or less "random" N, compute initially `N:=NextPrime(N)` to really start with a prime, then in a loop compute `P:=NextPrime(N)`, stop if `P-N=666` else `N:=P` and continue to next loop. Do that `M` times and if nothing is found, try another starting `N`. It worked on my third attempt, with initially $N=2222222222222222222$. I did this in GAP, but as long as you have a NextPrime function, it's ok. Notice that you get only "probable primes", as GAP uses a probabilistic primality test, but see [this](https://oeis.org/A014233).