# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+n}{\ln(x+n)}-\frac x {\ln x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is somewhat related to the discussions I had about [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972996/). It seems for every integer $n>1$ the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+n}{\ln(x+n)}-\frac x {\ln x}\right)$$
does exist. But I wasn't able to obtain a closed form for it (I admit that I didn't try enough). So, is there a closed form for it?

Comment: What makes you think that the limit is not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$\frac{x+n}{\ln(x+n)}-\frac{x}{\ln x}=((x+n)-x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)_{x=t}=n\left(\frac{1}{\ln t}-\frac{1}{\ln^2 t}\right)$$
with $x<t<x+n$. Now $t$ goes to infinity as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: The last part isn't really satisfactory, since we don't really know $t$... It's easier to note that $|n\left(\frac{1}{\ln t}-\frac{1}{\ln^2 t}\right) | \le n \left( \frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} \right)$, and now this obviously converges to zero.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi. We do not know $t$, but we know that $t>x$. Hence $x\to +\infty$ implies that $t\to +\infty$.

Comment: I'm not questioning the fact that your proof is correct, but a beginner could wonder whether you're really allowed to do what you did -- I just gave an alternative way of seeing the result.

Comment: Another question just popped into my mind, which I am too lazy to ask separately. In my question, what if we replace $n$ by $\ln x$? Maybe I'm wrong but, the mean value theorem doesn't look much promising in this case. It would be nice if you cover this case as well. Although I have consumed the only upvote that I could give, and don't have anything more to offer.

Comment: In that case the limit is 1 because $\frac{x}{\ln(x+\ln(x))}-\frac{x}{\ln x}\to 0$ and $\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x+\ln(x))}\to 1$.

Answer (score -2):

see my answer
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+n}{\ln(x+n)}-\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\left(1+\frac nx\right)}{\ln x\left(1+\frac{n}{x}\right)}-\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\left(1+\frac nx\right)}{\ln x+\ln \left(1+\frac{n}{x}\right)}-\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
$$=\frac{x\left(1+0\right)}{\ln x+\ln \left(1+0\right)}-\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
$$=\frac{x}{\ln x}-\frac{x}{\ln x}=0$$
the limit exists for all real n

Comment: I vaguely remember that we were not allowed to treat $\infty-\infty$ like this. The final answer seems right nonetheless

Comment: This is nonsense. A similar "proof" could "show" that the limit of $x(\ln(x+1) - \ln(x))$ would be zero as $x \to \infty$, even though the limit is actually $1$... You can't just take the limit of part of the expression, you have to take the limit of everything at once.